# Power BI - Working with multiple lines of the same information and calculating negatives

Tags: powerbi, report, ms-project

I am new to Power BI & Stackoverflow, so I really appreciate the help that I will be getting.

In my Power BI dataset I will return values like the following:

[example values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DvDo.png)

You can see that the BaselineFinish Date has passed and the Date is the Date of the report extract.

So what I need to try and achieve from a reporting function is to show 1 Line

Indicate that it has Slipped 2 (Twice) and the Total Days = -9

I have tried some of the 'Group By' Functions, but without success.

Comment: You'll need a project dimension. This should make reporting much easier. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/star-schema